# Get two previous and next rows data from current id SQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a table with database and i want get two data before current id and get two data after current id.

```
primary_key     id
1               345
2               356
3               400
4               102
5               210
6               190
```

**Case:**

- If current id defined **400**, the results as before is **356 & 345** and
  after is **102 & 210**
- If current id defined **210**, the results as before is **102 & 400** and
  after is **190**
- If current id defined **356**, the results as before is **345** and
  after is **400 & 102**
- If current id defined **345**, the results as before is **NULL** and
  after is **356 & 400**
- If current id defined **190**, the results as before is **210 & 102** and
  after is **NULL**

I try this SQL but not working fine,

```
$define_id = 400;

SELECT *
FROM table_name

WHERE ( 
    id = IFNULL(
        (
            SELECT MIN(id)
            FROM table_name
            WHERE id > $define_id
        ), 0 )

    OR id = IFNULL(
        (
            SELECT MAX(id)
            FROM table_name
            WHERE id < $define_id
        ), 0 )
) 

LIMIT 2
```

The code success to get before and after data, but only one before and one after. I want get result two before and two after.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried with the outputs you mentioned in the question. If this is not you want please explain more clearly.

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (
  `primary_key` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`primary_key`,`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `docs` (`primary_key`, `id`) VALUES
  ('1', '345'),
  ('2', '356'),
  ('3', '400'),
  ('4', '102'),
  ('5', '210'),
  ('6', '190');
```

Query

```
(SELECT * FROM docs WHERE primary_key < (SELECT primary_key FROM docs WHERE id = 400) ORDER BY primary_key DESC LIMIT 2)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM docs WHERE primary_key > (SELECT primary_key FROM docs WHERE id = 400) ORDER BY primary_key ASC LIMIT 2);
```

Sqlfiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e11c8d/2

Comment: i don't want get results based on primary_key, i want get result based on defined id.

Comment: But what you mentioned is you want to get results before and after a particular id. This uses primary key to get those results. If you want to get results based on the id value you must sort them first then fetch the results from them.

Comment: Nice, but how inlcude the define id to result.

Comment: You can replace 400 with your defined id. Search how can you implement  a stored procedure in mysql with parameters and implement the same.

Comment: Okay, thanks, after research. Now work fine as i want.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `union all` for the two groups:

```
(select 'before' as which, t.*
 from t cross join
      (select primary_key from t where id = $define_id) x
 where t.primary_key < x.primary_key
 order by t.primary_key desc
 limit 2
) union all
(select 'after' as which, t.*
 from t cross join
      (select primary_key from t where id = $define_id) x
 where t.primary_key > x.primary_key
 order by t.primary_key asc
 limit 2
);
```

Comment: But where the current id? i want get result from current id.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with min and max functions, So for next

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE  id = (select min(id) from `table` where id > YOUR_ID)
```

And for previous:

```
SELECT * from `table` where id = (select max(id) from table where id < YOUR_ID)
```

Comment: Thank you, but need only with one query

Comment: @Opsional You can use UNION to combine both of them in one query.